# How to make Angular Reactive (Dynamic) form with API Response data? Need advise

Tags: html, angular, forms, dynamic, angular-reactive-forms

```
[
  {
    "name": "jkjk",
    "firstName": "hgh",
    "lastName": "ehtrh",
    "replytype": "svdv",
    "prodCode": "svv",
    "executor": "ewwe",
    "skills": [
      {},
      {}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "sdkjbdsf",
    "firstName": "kdvbfd",
    "lastName": "dkbd",
    "replytype": "SQLServer",
    "prodCode": "vsdv",
    "executor": "vkjbndsf,vd",
    "skills": [
      {
        "name1": "abs"
      },
      {
        "name2": "bbs"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: this question is soooo raw! provide some info and explain the situation more clearly.

Comment: sure. i want to render API Response in Angular Form for edit purpose and to save again.

[
  {
    "name": "jkjk",
    "firstName": "hgh",
    "lastName": "ehtrh",
    "replytype": "svdv",
    "prodCode": "svv",
    "executor": "ewwe",
    "skills": [
      {},
      {}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "sdkjbdsf",
    "firstName": "kdvbfd",
    "lastName": "dkbd",
    "replytype": "SQLServer",
    "prodCode": "vsdv",
    "executor": "vkjbndsf,vd",
    "skills": [
      {
        "name1": "abs"
      },
      {
        "name2": "bbs"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: Let me know, if more information requiremed

Comment: You can go through [Building dynamic forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)

Comment: take a look to this tutorial :https://www.htmlelements.com/docs/angular-dynamic-forms/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dffny7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html this project is not working in angular 12. Can someone please help..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I recommend you to use a `*ngFor` loop and generate your inputs.

Add keys as the `name` property and the values as value.

Then you can post the data as the usual way back.

```
<form>
  <div *ngFor="let item of array">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of item | keyvalue">
      <input [name]=i.key [value]="i.value" />
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" (click)="edit()"></button>
</form>
```

- Use some conditional tags to provide other types of form tags (select, textarea, ...).